# React Native - How to permanently ban user

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I would like to ask for any suggestion how to reliably block user on iOS and Android, so that if i block his registered account, he cant just create new one. In the app i am working on, its rather important to make sure that the blocked users cant use the app again.

Solutions i considered:

1) Use phone number for verification. Phone number can be blocked so that user would need new phone number to register new account again. Problem is that phone verification is paid with all services i considered ( firebase, twilio ). Since the app is free, if the userbase would get larger, i would not be able to financially support it ( something like $0.06 per verification ).

2) Device ID. Use device ID to block the device. From what i read, it seems its prohibited and cant be used like that. Thats specified by Apple, or so i heard.

3) Itunes / Google Play account email. Is not possible to obtain it seems.

Comment: you can't ... you just have to make the signup process so long that no one would have fun doing it twice :)

Comment: I would suggest in iOS used DeviceCheck framework to detect the device. DeviceCheck framework intrduced by Apple for the same. For more info https://fluffy.es/devicecheck-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

There is no foolproof way to achieve that.

Using the user's phone number or physical address (eg send him a card with a code) is not free and as you said, it can add up if your base grows.

You might consider asking your users to photograph / upload their identity card and make sure the name on the card matches the name they give during the registration process, but that is not entirely foolproof either (they could ask a friend / neighbour). Nevertheless, this might be the cheapest / most secure solution (but it could alienate a portion of your users). You could also ask, in addition, to upload a utility bill with the user's name on it, but again... that will only work if people really want to use your app.

Good luck! Just remember even Amazon can't do it 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You can recognize and ban a mobile device access to your server by its Wifi or Bluetooth MAC Address.

Comment: But aren't people easily able to change their MAC address? Seems like it would be easy to circumvent ban